# Unable to Show Labels in Google Scatter Chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, scatter-plot

I seem to be unable to get this Google Chart Scatter Plot to display the score.partner as a label. I can only get them to show as tooltips.

What am I doing wrong?

```
drawChart: function() {
    var self = this;

    var gdpMin = parseFloat(self.scores[0].gdpScore);
    var gdpMax = gdpMin;
    var teaMin = parseFloat(self.scores[0].teaScore);
    var teaMax = teaMin;

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'GDP Score');
    data.addColumn('number', 'TEA Score');
    data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'label'});

    $.each(self.scores, function(i, score) {
        gdpScore = parseFloat(score.gdpScore);
        teaScore = parseFloat(score.teaScore);
        data.addRows([[gdpScore, teaScore, score.partner]]);

if (gdpScore < gdpMin) gdpMin = gdpScore;
        if (gdpScore > gdpMax) gdpMax = gdpScore;

if (teaScore < teaMin) teaMin = teaScore;
        if (teaScore > teaMax) teaMax = teaScore;
    });

    var options = {
      title: 'GDP and TEA Scores',
      hAxis: {title: 'GDP', minValue: gdpMin, maxValue: gdpMax},
      vAxis: {title: 'TEA', minValue: teaMin, maxValue: teaMax},
      legend: 'none',
      colors: ['#3B7CBF']
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you want to see, and what are you seeing? What labels are you expecing, and where are you expecting them? Generally speaking, scatter charts do not display labels on individual points without interacting with them. Of course you can make workarounds, but it wouldn't be default behavior.

Comment: Jim - I have provided enough information. The points and tooltips for the points work. I want labels, not tooltips. All of that info is in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From user **asgallant** in [Google Visualization API Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!forum/google-visualization-api):

> You want to label individual points on a ScatterChart?  **That isn't
>   supported.**  Depending on the structure of your data, you may be able
>   to use a LineChart in a manner similar to a ScatterChart.  See an
>   example here: jsfiddle.net/asgallant/YFMga/

There you have it. Labels are not supported for scatter plots using the Google Visualization API.

[jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bubble-plots.php) may be an acceptable alternative.

Comment: This is what I said in my comment above: "Generally speaking, scatter charts do not display labels on individual points without interacting with them. Of course you can make workarounds, but it wouldn't be default behavior." There are workarounds (such as using a bubble chart which **does** support labels), which is why I asked what you wanted to do rather than just answer "no you can't" which solves nothing.